# Image will not draw in webpage from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

The images i'm trying to draw will not work. When I run functions in javascript, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: context.drawImage is not a function
    at Image.drawing.onload (test.js:74)
test.js:82 Uncaught TypeError: context.drawImage is not a function
    at Image.drawing.onload (test.js:82)
```

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Maze</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #maze {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        #maze td {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="maze">
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<canvas>
<script>
    var disp = newMaze(20,20);
    for (var i = 0; i < disp.length; i++) {
        $('#maze > tbody').append("<tr>");
        for (var j = 0; j < disp[i].length; j++) {
            var selector = i+"-"+j;
            $('#maze > tbody').append("<td id='"+selector+"'>&nbsp;</td>");
            if (disp[i][j][0] == 0) { $('#'+selector).css('border-top', '2px 
solid black'); }
            if (disp[i][j][1] == 0) { $('#'+selector).css('border-right', '2px 
solid black'); }
            if (disp[i][j][2] == 0) { $('#'+selector).css('border-bottom', '2px 
solid black'); }
            if (disp[i][j][3] == 0) { $('#'+selector).css('border-left', '2px 
solid black'); }
        }
        $('#maze > tbody').append("</tr>");
    }
</script>
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function newMaze(x, y) {

// Establish variables and starting grid
var totalCells = x*y;
var cells = new Array();
var unvis = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < y; i++) {
    cells[i] = new Array();
    unvis[i] = new Array();
    for (var j = 0; j < x; j++) {
        cells[i][j] = [0,0,0,0];
        unvis[i][j] = true;
    }
}

// Set a random position to start from
var currentCell = [Math.floor(Math.random()*y), Math.floor(Math.random()*x)];
var path = [currentCell];
unvis[currentCell[0]][currentCell[1]] = false;
var visited = 1;

// Loop through all available cell positions
while (visited < totalCells) {
    // Determine neighboring cells
    var pot = [[currentCell[0]-1, currentCell[1], 0, 2],
        [currentCell[0], currentCell[1]+1, 1, 3],
        [currentCell[0]+1, currentCell[1], 2, 0],
        [currentCell[0], currentCell[1]-1, 3, 1]];
    var neighbors = new Array();

    // Determine if each neighboring cell is in game grid, and whether it has already been checked
    for (var l = 0; l < 4; l++) {
        if (pot[l][0] > -1 && pot[l][0] < y && pot[l][1] > -1 && pot[l][1] < x && unvis[pot[l][0]][pot[l][1]]) { neighbors.push(pot[l]); }
    }

    // If at least one active neighboring cell has been found
    if (neighbors.length) {
        // Choose one of the neighbors at random
        next = neighbors[Math.floor(Math.random()*neighbors.length)];

        // Remove the wall between the current cell and the chosen neighboring cell
        cells[currentCell[0]][currentCell[1]][next[2]] = 1;
        cells[next[0]][next[1]][next[3]] = 1;

        // Mark the neighbor as visited, and set it as the current cell
        unvis[next[0]][next[1]] = false;
        visited++;
        currentCell = [next[0], next[1]];
        path.push(currentCell);
    }
    // Otherwise go back up a step and keep going
    else {
        currentCell = path.pop();
    }
}
debugger
drawUser(currentCell[0],currentCell[1]);
var first = currentCell[0] + 10;
var second = currentCell[1] + 10;
if(first >= 20){
    first = currentCell[0] - 10;
}
if(second >= 20){
    second = currentCell[1] - 10;
}
drawJewel(first,second);
return cells;
}
function drawUser(x,y){
    var context = document.getElementById("maze");
    drawing = new Image();
    drawing.src = "img/userpic.png";
    drawing.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(drawing,x,y);
    };
}
function drawJewel(x,y){
    var context = document.getElementById("maze");
    drawing = new Image();
    drawing.src = "img/diamondpic.png";
    drawing.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(drawing,x,y);
    };
}
```

The canvas tags around the script tags in the HTML was one of my attempts at a fix, as well as the debugger in the JS code.

I'm new to jQuery but it needs to be used for generating the maze.
All i'm trying to do is display the images, diamondpic.png and userpic.png, both images 20x20 px drawn in paint, in the maze located in two separate, random cells. I'm not familiar with "canvas" or "context" and I think it is the issue.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `var context = document.getElementById("maze");` — `context` is an `HTMLTableElement`, not a `CanvasRenderingContext2D`.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of problems here. First, the `#maze` element is a table, not a canvas. If you want to use a canvas to draw your images, you need to draw on the canvas element, not a table.

Second, you need to define `context` as a 2d context of your canvas element.
Replace

`var context = document.getElementById("maze");`

with

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```